# Bing webmaster tool Url Submission API

Tags: bing

Where on my website should I place the URL submission API. I don't use WordPress, My website is made by WIX
I would be grateful if someone can help me
Thank You

Comment: The documentation doesn't give you that information?

Comment: no like there it's written JSON request sample code , I want to know that I have put the code in <HEAD> section of my website or somewhere else. https://www.bing.com/webmasters/url-submission-api#APIs

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://support.wix.com/en/article/verifying-your-site-with-bing-webmaster-tools) might help you, adding the `Bing` meta tag to your Wix site.